# For Loop returning all in string Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a for loop to return all the values within an array … at the moment it's returning them all in a string but I want them to return as individual values so I can do stuff with each one … heres my code so far…

```
function generateSelectors(product) {

      var i;
      if( product.attrs.available == false) {
            $('.variant-selectors, .buy-button').hide();
          } else {
                for (i = 0; i < product.attrs.options.length; i++) { 
                   var options = '<p>' + product.attrs.options[i].values + '</p>';
                }
          }
      $('.html').html(options);
}
```

Outputting as `<div class="html"><p>3(36),4(37),5(38),6(39),7(40)</p></div>`

What I'd like is …

```
<div class="html">
<p>3(36)</p>
<p>4(37)</p>
etc…
</div>
```

Thanks in advance, sure this is relatively easy.

Comment: This doesn't "return" anything. It certainly doesn't do anything with "all in a string", either, since you create a new string in each iteration.

Comment: can you please provide input ?

Comment: Is `options[i].values` an array? if you convert array to string, it will join all element by comma by default and return string

Comment: @PeterB Yes it can. If `values` is an array holding those values

Comment: @Rajesh `values` is an array `values: Array[5]` … sorry relatively new to this

Comment: @webcreator25 Please share `product.attrs`

Comment: @Jamiec Yes that is the issue but question is why OP is getting `<p>3(36),4(37),5(38),6...` and its because `values` is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do like below:-

```
function generateSelectors(product) {

    var i;
    var options =''; //define variable outside of loop
    if( product.attrs.available == false) {
        $('.variant-selectors, .buy-button').hide();
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < product.attrs.options.length; i++) {
            $.each(product.attrs.options[i].values ,function(key,val){//iterate over array
                options += '<p>' + val + '</p><br/>'; //append each value to variable
            });
        }
    }
    $('.html').html(options); // add full-data as HTML to element
}
```

Comment: Literally the opposite of what the OP said

Comment: That still returns as `<div class="html"><p>3(36),4(37),5(38),6(39),7(40)</p></div>`

Comment: I don't think you need `$.each`. You can use array functions as well. You can take reference from my deleted answer.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yep that worked! thank you … I just took the `<br/>` as the paragraph tags put a break in. Thanks again!

Comment: @webcreator25  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at `Array.prototype.map` - it's a functional way of doing exactly what you're trying to do with a manual `for` loop

```
function generateSelectors(product) {
  if (product.attrs.available == false) {
    $('.variant-selectors, .buy-button').hide();
  else
    $('.html').html(
      product.attrs.options.map(o => '<p>' + o.values + '</p>').join('')
    )
}
```